# What should I write when I send a CV by email?

Tags: cv

Sometimes for different purpose like taking new courses or job they tell to send a CV through email. But what should I write in body when I attach my CV?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question, as it stands, does not have anything to do with academia particularly. [Boat Programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470/196834).

Answer (score 1):

You should

1. Say why you are sending the CV.
2. Thank them for considering your application (or doing whatever they're doing).
3. Keep the body of the email relatively brief.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the body of the email taking the place of a cover letter (unless it was requested as a standalone document). Include items such as

- Why you are sending the CV (what position you are applying for) and
- Thanking the recipient for their consideration.

When you sign off the email, include all your contact information as you might in a business letter.